# Running a python script from different computers

Tags: python, arcgis, arcgis-server

We have a Python Script that when run from 4 different machines, produces 4 different results.

1 - Running in ArcMap: works fine

2 - Running in ArcMap: works once then fails to work until the environment its run under is restarted

3 - Running in ArcGIS Server: fails half way through the script

4 - Running in ArcGIS Server: fails a the start of the script

5 - Running it in Aptana: works fine

The script leverages other modules that we have built as well as win32COM.
Our guess is that each of them are having problems importing resources.

Any ideas of why this would be?

Comment: Not without seeing the script, no

Comment: And it would be helpful to provide log files/command line output of the successful and failing runs

Answer (score 0):

- Do all machines share the same software versions?
- Surround your imports with a `try...except` block to throw an
  exception if an import is not completed properly.

Try...Except:

```
try:
    import some_module
except ImportError:
    some_module = None
```